Getting attribute table value to dynamic text in QGIS layout
How can I use a value from an attribute table, e.g a value from column A, in order to make dynamic label?


The question is unclear, please add more information about your settings. Do you create an atlas? Which layer and which feature to you want to include in the text? As long as we don't have this information, we can just start guessing what you might want to achieve.

If you want to add a value from your attribute table, you can press "Insert/Edit Expression..." and add the column name as the expression in double quotes (e.g. "columnName")

@gHupf this does not work, as you must spefify the layer and the feature. OP is in layout mode, not in QGIS main window and OP seems to use a simple text field. This is why we must have more information about the intention (e.g. atlas)

i do not use atlas, i use manual layout and filter layer value that i want to show is by query on layer setting

There are ways to get attributes on the map if using the QGIS Atlas feature, but because you don't mention this, I will assume you are looking to get an attribute, from a feature present on your map.
To do this, add your text label as you have done, and head to the 'Insert/Edit Expression' button.
In the expression, you can use the attribute(get_feature('a','b','c'),'d') function, where:

'a' is the name of the feature you need to access
'b' is the id field or a field that contains an identifier for the feature you wish to isolate and grab an attribute from
'c' is the identifier value for this id
'd' is the field name you wish to display.

So as an example, if I have a feature called towns, and I want to mention the regio this town is located in, based on the values in its attribute table. I could use the following:
attribute(get_feature('Towns','id','1001'),'region')

Use the "Render as HTML" tickbox to make sure it looks good, and potentially add your own HTML to format as you need.

thank for you response, it work and i apply to my layout (get_feature('layer','field1','001'),'field1') and then i get 001 value in my textbox, right now if i wanna get other values as i change the filter of layer that has been shown on the main pages, can you show how to write the expression to make the text dynamically follow the value from layer that hase been filtered ?,  as u can see i show you how my data that i wanna show in text box

As it stands, I have answered your initial question. if you need more, then you will need to ask a new question. The GIS Stack Exchange isnt a forum, more of a focused Q&A site. Where one question is asked, covering one topic and then that is answered. I would take your answer below and ask a new question, expanding on this one.

this is my data example, i make select distinct because one value has more than hundread feature, to be honnest i wanna make valid my question, i do not use atlas because, when i try it the feature that show on layout is one by one not by filter

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
